# Git commit related issue - Commit currently takes login credentials of another user having similar priveleges

Tags: git, github, privileges

I've been made the collaborator(say, i'm User 1) of a git repository. Currently due to some settings which I must have wrongly done unknowingly, all commits are being committed as if being done by the owner(another user - say user 2) who has shared the access with me.

I guess while doing a git clone of the rep. I had done something wrong.

How can I get myself as the owner of each commit?

What do I need to change?. I'm just currently aware of a `.git/config` file .

What precautions do I need to take to avoid this in the future.

Thank you very much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your:

- user.name
- user.email
- github.user
- github.token

in order to be able to push directly your commits to the repo where you are now a collaborator. See [GitHub help](http://help.github.com/set-your-user-name-email-and-github-token/).
The email must be the one used with your GitHub account.

You could also, through a filter-branch, reset the author name and email of your previous commits, and force a push (but that will rewrite history, so you need to make sure that won't bother anyone else who would have already clone the repo).

Comment: VonC: Thanks for your useful inputs, do I need to use the email id as given in the public profile of my account..?

Comment: @boddhisattva: no, the one in your "Email Addresses" field of your "Account setting": that might be the same than your public visible email, but again, it can be different. So consider only the one entered in that "Email addresses" section.

Comment: Thank you , it works well now.. . Any suggestions on how to avoid such a case in the future..?

Comment: @boddhisattva: a global config (as suggested below) is a good start in order to make sure those settings will apply for any of your local repos (cloned from GitHub or not). To remember what could go in those global settings (which are in `%HOME%/.gitconfig`), you can create yourself a Gist (without any sensitive information of course). Here's mine for instance: https://gist.github.com/972690

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `.git/config` file doesn't contain the other person's username and email address. If it does, remove them.

This should generally be set globally in each user's own ~/.gitconfig file; you can do it like this:

```
$ git config --global user.name  "Your Name"
$ git config --global user.email "your@email.address"
```

Comment: The .git/config file doesn't contain any fields like username and email address.. Am I missing something...?